# iPhone - Loading UIView with Custom UI from nib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nib, init

I have a UIView and I initialize it from a nib file.

In my nib file I dragged and dropped a UIImageView and I changed the class name to MyImage.

When i load the view it doesn't seem like it's initializing the the image using my custom class, because the init method is not getting called.
Any idea what the problem is?

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MyImage *image;
@end

@implementation MyView
@synthesize image;

- (id)init
{
   self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
   return self;
}
@end
```

Here is MyImage
Here is my Image

```
@interface MyImage : UIImageView
@end

@implementation MyImage
- (id)init
{
   // This doesn't get called 
   self = [super init];
   if (self) 
   {
      // do somethin
   }
   return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: I'm new to iOS so please forgive me for such question. Does really `UIView` have `initWithNibName: bundle` initializer? as you've used it in your code snippet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initializer that's used when loading a view from a nib is `-initWithCoder:`, not `-init`. From the [UIView reference page](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html):

> initWithCoder:—Implement this method if you load your view from an
>   Interface Builder nib file and your view requires custom
>   initialization.

Moreover, if you're instantiating the view programmatically, the usual initializer is `-initWithFrame:`.

So, change your `-init` method to `-initWithCoder:`, or implement `-initWithCoder:` such that it calls your `-init`.

Comment: Can you explain how to use/override this methos?

Comment: [View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW23).

Comment: Thanks a lot one more thing, If I want to be able to init with code and from nib, am I suppose to implement both methods?

Comment: The typical thing is to create your own method that has all the initialization code that's common to both `-initWithCoder:` and `-initWithFrame:`. You can then call that method from both places so that it runs no matter how you instantiate the view.

Answer (score 1):

Caleb is right, implement it like so :

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        // other stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: your `-(id)init;` method will never get called, do your stuff in `-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;`. Your view is 'deserialized' from the nib file.

Answer (score 0):

I though awakeFromNib was safer as all outlets wired up correctly

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        //self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        // other stuff
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    ..setup view
}
```

Called in order:

```
initWithCoder
awakeFromNib
```

Comment: Can you write how to call initWithCoder with the parameter?